# Slow API execution in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a flow in Azure Logic Apps that consume some API services, in AzureLogicApps the execution is very fast, but when performing the same process in Azure DataFactory the process becomes much much slower, what could be the reason?

[image: LogicApp Api Configuration:]

The process in ADF runs in a ForEach Loop

[image: Web Activity Configuration in ADF]

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, it may caused by the for each loop in data factory. When request the api in for each loop, it may complete the first few times fast. But when loop many times, it will take much more time to complete each request.

It seems you configure the api in azure api management. The root cause of this problem is your original api can just process a request in 1 second(just for example). But many requests will be sent to request the api in for each loop(**in parallel**). So some requests will be queued. You can set the for each loop to execute the request one by one by enable "**Sequential**" as below screenshot.

[image]

After this configuration, the request will be executed one by one. Each of them will not take much more time, **but I think the total time may not reduce**.

Or you should improve the load of your api (if it is possible) to allow more request be executed at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, what makes me curious is that in LogicApp the execution is much faster than in ADF so I wonder if both the api and the ADF have to be in the same resource group ?.

Analyzing the executions in ADF I see that the api is slower than the PUT method

Comment: @willysepulveda I don't think it will be better if you put APIM and ADF in the same resource group. It may be faster if you put them in same region(but the impact is also small). By the way, did you also put the HTTP action in For each loop in logic app ?

Comment: Both services are in the same location, regarding your question: did you also set the HTTP action to For each loop in the logic app?, The answer is yes

Comment: @willysepulveda You can go to your logic app and click `...` button of the "For each" action, then toggle the `Concurrency Control`. Then test if it will also execute slow in logic app.

Comment: @Huty Sehcn the foreach in the logic app is configured to run sequentially

Comment: An Execution of the API is carried out in PostMan where the execution is also very slow when receiving the response from the API, apparently it is because it does not resolve the message that the API returns, it is possible that this same behavior is happening in the web activity of ADF